# Как сделать перенаправление на одностраничный сайт

Tags: linux, сеть, bind

Есть сервер bind9, на этом сервере заблокировано несколько доменов, перенаправление идет на 127.0.0.1(localhost).

Как сделать перенаправление на одностраничный сайт в духе: "Эти домены заблокированы"?

Comment: сделайте сайт "этот домен заблокирован" и перенаправляйте на него. Делов то.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что для перенаправления bind нужен ip-шник, а для этого надо поднимать docker, nginx, туда пихать одностраничный сайт и т.д. или это можно сделать как-то ещё?

Comment: bind - это "dns",  а значит сервер Вы должны сами поднять. Но докер для этого не нужен.

Comment: А как его лучше всего поднять, сделать это на локальном ip или нужен белый?

Comment: можно и на локальном. Главное, что бы для всех пользователей Вашего bind этот ip был доступен (это вполне может быть тот же сервер/айпи, чтои сервер с bind. но вот 127.0.0.1 точно не подходит).

Comment: Как изящнее сервер поднять для двух подсетей тогда (172.16.100.0/24, 10.0.0.0/8)? Я так понимаю все равно нужно это все делать в виртуалке.

Comment: просто поднимите nginx, который будет случать все входящее и все будет работать. А потом уже будете думать, куда и как ограничить. А вот что за виртуалка у Вас - я не знаю.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В конечном счете, сделали одностраничный сайт, поставили nginx на сервер с bind, создали виртуальный хост на локальном IP(10.0.1.27:80), и настроили перенаправление с 127.0.0.1 на 10.0.1.27.